# The system cannot find the file specified executable from java

Tags: java, executable

I have got a code which is stands for running an executable from java code. The program run smoothly until today. I dont know what I have changed however I am receiving the following error:

> Cannot run program "\Release\program.exe" (in directory "I:\Release\"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

The code I am using is the following:

```
Process proc = rt.exec("Release\\program.exe", null, new File("I:\\Release\\"));
```

What could be the problem here? It used to work fine.

**EDIT:** `Process proc = rt.exec("program.exe", null, new File("I:\\Release\\"));`

I got the same error. If I command from the explorer

```
> I:\\Release\\program.exe
```

this works fine

Comment: Is there a folder named "Release" in the path I:\Release?

Comment: Does file `I:\Release\Release\program.exe` exist?

Comment: "Andreas I know it is weird it was the way it worked until know. If I remove the release it wont be work either. From the explorer I run the following command: I:\Release\program.exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this ?

```
// Java runtime
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
// Command
String command = "I:/Release/program.exe" ;
// Process
Process process = runtime.exec(command, null, new File("I:/Release"));
```

Comment: Okay this thing worked. But why? What is the difference?

Comment: I can't explain. I already used this in the past and I had no problem. The only things I can say is that you should use `/` instead of `\\` for paths even if you're on Windows with Java. Also you should use absolute path for programs and not relative paths.

Comment: @Jose I just had the same problem and ended up digging through the source of [`ProcessBuilder.start`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#start--), which led me to the [Windows `CreateProcess` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx). The doc for `lpCommandLine` explains where it looks for the program. As far as I can tell, directory is only set so the command can get the desired cwd, but it's not used for finding the command itself.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your folder structure looks like this:

```
I:\Release\program.exe
```

Your code would then have to look like this:

```
Process proc = rt.exec("program.exe", null, new File("I:\\Release\\"));
```

**EDIT:** Try this instead:

```
ProcessBuilder proc = new ProcessBuilder("I:\\Release\\program.exe");
proc.start();
```

Comment: I got the same with ProcessBuilder, :(